# Emailing on Server without mail function

Tags: php, linux, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

On website, I have a form with some fields and one file upload control. The filled form should be sent to an email along with the uploaded photograph.

I have only `FTP` access to a web server. I have tried but `mail()` funtion is not working, seems like it has been blocked by the admin.

Since I have `FTP` only, I cannot execute any installation commands on live server. So, Pear package installation is not possible, as per my knowledge. I have always worked with CPanel only.

I have tried PHPMailer library, but its also not working with the following test code:

```
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->setFrom('admin@test.com', 'Your Name');
    $mail->addAddress('testemail@gmail.com', 'My Friend');
    $mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
    $mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';
    if(!$mail->send()) {
      echo 'Message was not sent.';
      echo 'Mailer error: ';
    } else {
      echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
```

on submitting form, it says

*`websitename` took too long to respond.*
*`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`*

### Update:

Now, i am trying it on localhost
I have downloaded the PHPMailer library from this url:
[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

I extracted the zip file into my project folder. PHPMailer contains folder src. Now the updated code is as under:

```
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setFrom('admin@test.com', 'Your Name');
    $mail->addAddress('testemail@gmail.com', 'My Friend');
    $mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
    $mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';
    if(!$mail->send()) {
      echo 'Message was not sent.';
      echo 'Mailer error: ';
    } else {
      echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found

---

### Update

Now I have tried PHPMailer 5.2.0 on localserver as well as live server through FTP (I donot have Cpanel access) with the following code:

```
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

    try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

        $body = "helo";
        $mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP server port
        $mail->Host       = "mail.testserver.com"; // SMTP server
        $mail->Username   = "mail@testserver.com";     // SMTP server username
        $mail->Password   = "mypass";            // SMTP server password

        $mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail

        $mail->AddReplyTo("mail@testserver.com","First Last");

        $mail->From       = "mail@testserver.com";
        $mail->FromName   = "First Last";

        $to = "targetuser@gmail.com";

        $mail->AddAddress($to);

        $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";

        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
        $mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

        $mail->MsgHTML($body);

        $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

        $mail->Send();
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage();
    }
```

With this piece of code, my new error is:

*Could not execute: /var/qmail/bin/sendmail*

how can i resolve the issue?

Comment: How does it show, that `mail()` is — not — working?

Comment: I tried sending the emails and it got failed. I have seen many companies disabling the mail() function on linux servers recently

Comment: Which version of phpmailer did you download, the second snippet is not how you do it. the top version looks like outbound connections are blocked.

Comment: Read the readme on how to load PHPMailer correctly, and I recommend learning how to use composer. If your call to `mail()` fails, it suggests you don't have a mail server installed, which means that PHPMailer can't use it either - so you need to use SMTP directly instead, which PHPMailer can also do - see the examples provided.

Comment: does your server have a smtp server installed?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Hi, it looks 6.0.5 .... the link to this version is provided in the description.

Comment: @All I have now tried PHPMailer 5.2.0 with SMTP, but it again seems non working. The credentials that I have passed for SMTP are now of my personal server, while the website will be uploaded to other server whose FTP access is only available.

Comment: Don't call `isSendmail()`; It has nothing to do with what you're trying to do. Like I said earlier, base your code on the examples provided, and use the latest version, not the old 5.2.